# Simba Spark ODBC Driver is not working ms excel

Tags: excel, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, simba

I am using Spark(1.5.0) for utilizing Spark-SQL feature using Spark ThriftServer application and also using Simba Spark ODBC Driver for getting connection.

Using Tableau, I am able to connect and able to do Spark-SQL operations.

But when, I tried to connect Spark-SQL to MS-Excel, It goes connected but not listing database and table names. And I also tried `Microsoft Query` option of MS-Excel according to [Doc](http://cdn.simba.com/products/Spark/doc/Simba_Spark_ODBC_QuickstartGuide.pdf) to execute custom SQL queries (`select * default.airline`), but it's throwing error with query (`select * from SPARK.default.airline`) with catalog name **`SPARK`**.

Problem is that how to remove that catalog name from the query, I tried with all the available options.

Answer (score 0):

I work as a Sales Engineer with Simba.  The Simba Spark driver should work in Excel with both MS Query and through the Connection Wizard.

Can you please provide more information on this problem?  You can enable driver logging through the configuration options in ODBC Administrator.  Choose your DSN, go to logging options, and set it to TRACE.

Then restart Excel and try the query again.

Send the logs and a screenshot of your DSN to sales@simba.com

Thanks,
Jeff